# Click Multiple links and get their url

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get the detail page urls of the match links on this webpage: https://www.sportybet.com/ke/sport/football/today

What I want?
I want to click on Man city vs PSG, copy the detail match url and print.. and do the same for the next match, Holstein Kiel vs SV Sandhausen and likewise for all the matches on the web page.

I have this code selenium below for just 1 match;

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="importMatch"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]').click()
get_url = driver.current_url
print(get_url)
```

I need help to get all the match urls with a loop or any better suggestions.

Comment: What exceptions you getting?

Comment: The code works and retrieves a single match url... i need the code to get all the match urls

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you asking for, you should do the following:

```
links = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='match-league']//div[contains(@class,'market-size')]")  
for link in links:
    link.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    url = driver.current_url
    print(get_url)
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    time.sleep(2)
```

On the first line you collecting the elements you can click to expand
Then with `for` loop iterate thru all these elements, click each one of them, get the `URL` and go back to the main page

Comment: I tried your code, It only gets the fiirst url and gives error:::  Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: The first url is printed but when it returns to the start page, it does not go to the next link